# How to marge data from the table using sql server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hi i am create the one store procedure for the get data and send push notification.and i want to marge this data and get in to one raw. but how can do that i don't know. i need help please help me let me know how can do that.this is my query here below i have write :

This is query =>

```
SELECT N.NotificationId,
   N.UserId,
   N.ActionUserId,
   (CASE WHEN N.NotificationTypeId = 1 THEN 1
              WHEN N.NotificationTypeId = 7 THEN 3
            ELSE    
                 2
        END) AS TypeId,                         
    AU.ProfileImage,
    AU.UserName,
    N.IsRead,
    (CASE WHEN N.NotificationTypeId = 1 THEN 1
          WHEN N.NotificationTypeId = 7 THEN 3
        ELSE    
             2
    END) AS TypeId,         
    N.NotificationTypeId,
    N.InsertDateTime
  FROM Notifications N
  INNER JOIN Users U ON N.UserId = U.UserId
  INNER JOIN Users AU ON N.ActionUserId = AU.UserId      
  ORDER BY N.InsertDateTime DESC
```

This is my current o/p =>

```
 NotificationId | UserId | ActionUserId | UserName | NotificationTypeId | InsertDateTime            | ProfileImage 
  6                20        15             hbc        1                    2017-06-22 17:14:16.803    20170416032403869.jpeg
  5                20        16             tyu        1                    2017-06-22 17:12:12.297     20170416031522534.jpeg
  4                20        17             opl        1                    2017-06-22 17:11:58.060     20170416031250102.jpeg
  3                10        11             abc        1                    2017-06-22 16:14:16.803    20170416032403867.jpeg
  2                10        12             xyz        1                    2017-06-22 16:14:12.297     20170416031522533.jpeg
  1                10        13             rty        1                    2017-06-22 16:13:58.060     20170416031250101.jpeg
```

This is my expected o/p =>

```
  NotificationId | UserId | ActionUserId | UserName | NotificationTypeId | InsertDateTime            | ProfileImage           | NotificationText
   6                20        15             hbc        1                    2017-06-22 17:14:16.803    20170416032403869.jpeg    hbc,tyu and 1  other users followed you
   3                10        11             abc        1                    2017-06-22 16:14:16.803    20170416032403867.jpeg    abc,xyz and 1  other users followed you
```

i want to like this marge this data any one know how can do that please let me know.

Comment: Your output does not match your query...

Comment: i know NotificationText column is not mention in the query but it's my expected o/p

Comment: Where does `InsertDateTime` come from for example?

Comment: @iamdave now it's correct i have add date column can you please help me how can do that

Comment: @iamdave how can do that any idea please let me know

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Please, define the criteria you want to apply to get the only row. Do you want one row for each UserID or just one sigle row?

Comment: @iamdave sql server 2014

Comment: @USeptim UserId suppose 10 and this related 5 data so i want last 5 of the data same as a onther user

Comment: @USeptim see i have edit the my both o/p now please help me how can do that

Comment: So, it looks like for each UserId you want the row with highest notification Id. Isn't it?

Comment: @USeptim yes i need like this

Comment: Your query specifies just one `UserID`, but your output includes two.  Will the need to run for one `UserID` at a time or across all of them?

Comment: @iamdave sorry i forgot to delete where condition in the query now you can check this is my utility so here not come any where conditon on userid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a derived table and some windowed functions.  I have also added in a bit of logic to make sure the `Notification Text` has the correct English depending on the number of other users included:

```
-- Create test data
declare @Notifications table(NotificationID int, UserID int, ActionUserID int, NotificationTypeID int, InsertDateTime datetime);
declare @Users table(UserID int, UserName nvarchar(10), ProfileImage nvarchar(50))
insert into @Notifications values (6,20,15,1,'2017-06-22 17:14:16.803'),(5,20,16,1,'2017-06-22 17:12:12.297'),(4,20,17,1,'2017-06-22 17:11:58.060'),(3,10,11,1,'2017-06-22 16:14:16.803'),(2,10,12,1,'2017-06-22 16:14:12.297'),(1,10,13,1,'2017-06-22 16:13:58.060');
insert into @Users values (15,'hbc','20170416032403869.jpeg'),(16,'tyu','20170416031522534.jpeg'),(17,'opl','20170416031250102.jpeg'),(10,'aaa',''),(11,'abc','20170416032403867.jpeg'),(12,'xyz','20170416031522533.jpeg'),(13,'rty','20170416031250101.jpeg');


-- Specify UserID
declare @UserID int = 10;

-- Create Notification
with d as
(
    select n.NotificationID
          ,n.UserID
          ,n.ActionUserID
          ,au.UserName
          ,n.NotificationTypeID
          ,n.InsertDateTime
          ,au.ProfileImage
          ,row_number() over (partition by n.UserID order by n.InsertDateTime desc) as rn
          ,count(*) over (partition by n.UserID) as c
    from @Notifications n
        join @Users au
            on(n.ActionUserID = au.UserID)
)
select d.NotificationID
        ,d.UserID
        ,d.ActionUserID
        ,d.UserName
        ,d.NotificationTypeID
        ,d.InsertDateTime
        ,d.ProfileImage
        ,d.UserName
         + isnull(case when d2.c = 2
                       then ' and '
                       else ', '
                       end
                  + d2.UserName
                  ,'')
         + case when d2.c > 2
                then ' and ' + cast(d2.c-2 as nvarchar(10)) + ' other users'
                else ''
                end
         + ' followed you' as NotificationText
from d
    left join d as d2
        on(d.UserID = d2.UserID
            and d2.rn = 2
            )
where d.rn = 1;
```

Output:

```
+----------------+--------+--------------+----------+--------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| NotificationID | UserID | ActionUserID | UserName | NotificationTypeID |     InsertDateTime      |      ProfileImage      |            NotificationText             |
+----------------+--------+--------------+----------+--------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|              3 |     10 |           11 | abc      |                  1 | 2017-06-22 16:14:16.803 | 20170416032403867.jpeg | abc, xyz and 1 other users followed you |
|              6 |     20 |           15 | hbc      |                  1 | 2017-06-22 17:14:16.803 | 20170416032403869.jpeg | hbc, tyu and 1 other users followed you |
+----------------+--------+--------------+----------+--------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: or with out give any userid in the where condition then it's give more user?

Comment: Hello can you please give me hint on with out where condition i need 2 user for User id 10 and user id 20 so please give me hint and help me

Comment: @coderwill  I have updated my answer.  Please be aware that Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service and we do not work for you.  Please do not keep chasing for updates.  If we are going to help you, we will do so in our own time.

Comment: yes i know this thing so sorry for that and thank you so much for the helping

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT Q.NotificationId,
   Q.UserId,
   Q.ActionUserId,
   (CASE WHEN Q.NotificationTypeId = 1 THEN 1
              WHEN Q.NotificationTypeId = 7 THEN 3
            ELSE    
                 2
        END) AS TypeId,                         
    Q.ProfileImage,
    Q.UserName,
    Q.IsRead,
    (CASE WHEN Q.NotificationTypeId = 1 THEN 1
          WHEN Q.NotificationTypeId = 7 THEN 3
        ELSE    
             2
    END) AS TypeId2,         
    Q.NotificationTypeId,
    Q.InsertDateTime
  FROM ( SELECT    N.UserId, N.ActionUserId, N.NotificationTypeId,
      AU.ProfileImage, AU.UserName, N.IsRead, N.InsertDateTime,         N.NotificationID
    FROM Notifications N
        INNER JOIN Users U ON N.UserId = U.UserId
        INNER JOIN Users AU ON N.ActionUserId = AU.UserId
    WHERE N.UserId = @UserId  )  Q                                
    INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(NotificationID) AS MaxNotifID, UserID FROM         
dbo.Notifications  
        WHERE UserID = @userID GROUP BY UserID ) R ON
            Q.NotificationID  = R.MaxNotifID AND Q.UserID = R.USerID 
  ORDER BY Q.InsertDateTime DESC
```